# Extract value from span using xpath

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get the price from the span class that looks like this:
(source:https://www.leadhome.co.za/property/die-hoewes/centurion/lh-114269/lovely-3-bedroom-unit-for-sale-in-die-hoewes)

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div>
     <strong>Levy</strong>
     <span class="pull-right">R2,343</span>
```

I am trying to do this in the following way but it does not return anything:

```
levy = response.xpath('//span[@class="pull-right"][contains(text(), "Levy")]/text()').get()
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//span[@class="pull-right" and contains(../strong/text(), "Levy")]/text()
```

or, in a whole

```
levy = response.xpath('//span[@class="pull-right" and contains(../strong/text(), "Levy")]/text()').get()
```

---

An alternative is matching the `<div>` (if it has only one `<span>` child):

```
//div[span/@class="pull-right" and contains(strong, "Levy")]/span/text()
```

The output is, in both cases:

> R2,343

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the contains statement isn't going to work since your xpath starts at the `span` element.  By starting at the parent `div` tag you can confirm that both the strong tag and the span match what you expect.

```
//div/strong[contains(text(), "Levy")]/following-sibling::span[@class="pull-right"]
```